# Create an empty list of arrays in Jackson

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson, json-serialization

I'm using `Jackson` to serialize and deserialize `JSON` objects to and from `POJO`-s.

One of the elements I'm trying to create is a list of arrays (I think that's what this would be called).

```
"Images": [
{}
],
```

I've tried:

```
public ArrayList<String> Images = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and then just didn't add anything to it then called the object mapper.

That unfortunately gave me just a list:

```
"Images":[
]
```

I then tried to make it an list of string arrays:

```
public ArrayList<String[]> Images = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

I added an empty array to my ArrayList:

```
String[] tempArray = {};
Images.add(tempArray);
```

But that gave me:

```
"Images":[
     []
],
```

How can I get the needed format?

Answer (score 2):

What you describing is a list of objects, which would be:

```
public ArrayList<yourObject> Images = new ArrayList<yourObject>();
```

This would give you the:

```
"Images": [
{}
]
```

If you want a list of arrays, you would do:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<yourObject> Images = new ArrayList<ArrayList<yourObject>();
```

this would give you:

```
    "Images":[
     []
     ]
```

Answer (score 1):

`JSON` not-primitives in `Java` can be represented by:

1. `JSON Array` - `[]` => `java.util.List` or array.
2. `JSON Object` - `{}` => `java.util.Map` or `POJO` class.

If you need empty `JSON Object` you can use empty map or empty `POJO` - `POJO` without properties or with all properties set to `null` and with `ObjectMapper` set to ignore `null`-s.

Simple example which generates desired output could look like below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(new Root());
        System.out.println(json);
    }

}

class Root {

    private static final List<Map<String, Object>> EMPTY_MAP_IN_ARRAY = Collections.singletonList(Collections.emptyMap());

    @JsonProperty("Images")
    private List<Map<String, Object>> images = EMPTY_MAP_IN_ARRAY;

    public List<Map<String, Object>> getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    public void setImages(List<Map<String, Object>> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{"Images":[{}]}
```